# include_once(Zend\Uri\Http.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: zend-framework, yii, youtube-api

I'm using Zend framework with Yii to create a upload video function using the Youtube API. I got this error

`include_once(Zend\Uri\Http.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory` when trying to use `Zend_Gdata_AuthSub::getAuthSubSessionToken($_GET['token'])`. I have the ZendAutoloader and I'm developing with the Yii framework. What is the problem here?

Comment: Is the file there? Are the paths/permissions correct?

Comment: Did you try to use the Yii::import Method?

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework uses it's own auto-loader, as you mentioned, which I believe may be fighting with Yii's autoloader.

[Here's a nice blog post](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/101/how-to-use-phpexcel-external-library-with-yii/) with a great example of how to achieve integration with third party tools, but the gist of it is to turn off the Yii autloader, load your class, and then reload the Yii autloader.

```
// get a reference to the path of PHPExcel classes 
$phpExcelPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.phpexcel.Classes');

// Turn off our amazing library autoload 
spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));        

// Include your external library file.
include($phpExcelPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'PHPExcel.php');

// Application logic.

// Once we have finished using the library, give back the power to Yii... 
spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```